# flipInX not working as expected on smaller resolutions

Tags: css, safari

This problem seems to only happen on Safari (I tested on version 9.0.2).

If I scale my screen down to 565px width, or smaller, refresh the page, the `<article>`'s I have applied `flipInX` to flash on the screen and don't appear.

If I remove the `margin-bottom: 40px;` CSS from the `<article>` block, then it works.

Is this a bug in Safari?

**[Example](http://test.michaeldelle.com)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this CSS

```
.main {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(60px);
}
```